# No puedo instalar la libreria de python: opencv

Tags: python, terminal, opencv

Version de python 3.11.4

Version de opencv-python 4.8.0.74

Version de pip 23.2.1

M CMD de windows:

```
Microsoft Windows [Versión 10.0.19045.3208]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. Todos los derechos reservados.

C:\Users\saidn>pip install opencv-python
Collecting opencv-python
  Using cached opencv-python-4.8.0.74.tar.gz (92.1 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [79 lines of output]
Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.8" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version <= "3.9" and sys_platform == "linux" and platform_machine == "aarch64"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version <= "3.9" and sys_platform == "darwin" and platform_machine == "arm64"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.9" and platform_machine != "aarch64" and platform_machine != "arm64"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.10" and platform_system == "Darwin"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.11"' don't match your environment
  Collecting cmake>=3.1
    Using cached cmake-3.27.0.tar.gz (35 kB)
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Getting requirements to build wheel: started
    Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
    Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
  Collecting numpy==1.21.2
    Using cached numpy-1.21.2.zip (10.3 MB)
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Getting requirements to build wheel: started
    Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error

    Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
    exit code: 1

    [40 lines of output]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 112, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
        backend = _build_backend()
      File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 77, in _build_backend
        obj = import_module(mod_path)
      File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 887, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "C:\Users\saidn\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ksjx1mbg\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 253, in <module>
        monkey.patch_all()
      File "C:\Users\saidn\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ksjx1mbg\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 101, in patch_all
        patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler()
      File "C:\Users\saidn\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ksjx1mbg\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 164, in patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler
        patch_func(*msvc9('find_vcvarsall'))
      File "C:\Users\saidn\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ksjx1mbg\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 151, in patch_params
        mod = import_module(mod_name)
      File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 887, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "C:\Users\saidn\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ksjx1mbg\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 295, in <module>
        raise DistutilsPlatformError("VC %0.1f is not supported by this module" % VERSION)
    distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: VC 6.0 is not supported by this module
    [end of output]

    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1

  See above for output.

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Le pregunte a ChatGPT por que pasaba esto y me dijo que tenia que instalar Vs build tools o el copilador de C++ VS.

Tambien me recomendo actualizar el pip

Hice todo esto pero no resolvio nada.

No tengo insatalado CMake ni numpy. Pero entiendo que ya me lo instala la libreria automaticamente.

```
Installing build dependencies ... error
```

Me dice que hay un error con las dependencias, pero no entiendo cual es este error.

Nose porque pasa esto, pero si alguien que entenda más la terminal de windows me puede ayudar se lo agradeceria mucho.

Comment: "VC 6.0 is not supported by this module"